# What's the cleanest way to print an equally-spaced list in python?

Tags: python

Please close if this is a duplicate, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873927/printing-evenly-spaced-table-from-a-list-with-a-for-loop) does not answer my question as I would like to print a list, not elements from a list.

For example, the below does not work:

```
mylist = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
print(%3s % mylist)
```

Desired output:

```
[  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15]
```

Basically, if all items in the list are `n` digits or less, equal spacing would give each item `n+1` spots in the printout. Like `setw` in c++. Assume `n` is known.

If I have missed a similar SO question, feel free to vote to close.

Comment: Just a nitpick, it is called a `list` in python, not an `array` :-)

Comment: @bgse In Python an `array` is a collection of all same objects. https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exploit formatting as in the example below.  If you really need the square braces then you will have to fiddle a bit

```
lst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

frmt = "{:>3}"*len(lst)

print(frmt.format(*lst))
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Answer (score 3):

```
items=range(10)
''.join(f'{x:3}' for x in items)
'  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9'
```

Answer (score 1):

If none of the other answers work, try this code:

```
    output = ''
    space = ''
    output += str(list[0])
    for spacecount in range(spacing):
        space += spacecharacter
    for listnum in range(1, len(list)):
        output += space
        output += str(list[listnum])
    print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best yet, as it allows you to manipulate list as you wish. even numerically.

```
mylist = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
print(*map(lambda x: str(x)+" ",a))
```